# Схема база данных для склада оборудования

Tags: база-данных, проектирование, sql

Нужно организовать *учет оборудования*. Причем так, чтобы каждый конкретный экземпляр однозначно идентифицировался (серийным номером). Оборудование приходит на склад из **заказов с завода**, после этого оно может **сдаваться клиенту**. Есть ли какие-то схемы базы данных для этого случая?

***Схема, которую я придумал на данный момент:***

**ОборудованиеНаСкладе**: Склад (внеш. ключ), Оборудование (справочник, внеш. ключ), Серийный номер

**Заказ**: Дата создания и выполнения, состояние, завод (внеш), оборудование_в_заказе

**Оборудование в заказе**: Склад, Оборудование, Серийный номер.

**Выдача**: Дата создания, клиент (внеш), оборудование_в_выдаче.

**ОборудованиеВВыдаче**: Склад, Оборудование, Серийный номер.

Вопрос в том, нормально ли будет работать такая схема?

Comment: Слишком краткое описание задачи.

Comment: Задавайте дополнительные вопросы (:

Comment: Для этого есть не схемы баз, а куча софта от 1с до аксапты... Что конкретно интересует?

Comment: Обновил вопрос. Подсчет будет производиться группировкой и сложением..

Answer (score 2):

Первая таблица:

```
pnumber | description | ... | ... | ... | amount
```

Вторая таблица(клиенты):

```
id | limit | name | contacts
```

Третья таблица(аренда):

```
id_client | pnumber | amount
```

- pnumber - партномер. Лучше varchar или int. Является индексом.
- description - произвольный текст
- остальные параметры по мере надобности.
- amount - количество на складе/у клиента
- limit - максимальное количество, которое может взять клиент(или суммарная стоимость)
- name - имя-идентификатор
- contacts - произвольно.

Comment: Серийный номер выбит на каждом экземпляре оборудования, т.е. оно поштучно выдается, а не партиями.

Comment: тогда либо amount =1 всегда, либо вообще можно от этой колонки отказаться. Логично же

Answer (score 1):

Схема у вас получается выдернутой из бизнес-процесса. Такое начало обрастает в итоге кучей других смежных данных, например суммами, как следствие взаиморасчетами, амортизацией, далее контролем за возвратом оборудования и т.д.

Схема напоминает домашнюю библиотеку, какую книжку (или если хотите dvd) купил, кому дал почитать, на какой полке стоит. Для такого простого случая схема вполне рабочая, даже есть лишнее.

Простейший вариант - название оборудования, серийный номер, дата закупки, завод у которого куплено, склад, выдано клиенту, дата выдачи. Этого вполне достаточно, другие таблицы не нужны. И забить все это в Эксель.

Но для бизнеса такая схема не подойдет, слишком мало информации можно получить, слишком много информации надо вводить. Если у вас есть заказчик, то он попросит:

- взаиморасчеты с поставщиками (что и за сколько куплено за период, была ли оплата)
- взаиморасчеты с покупателями/комитентами (что и за сколько выдано и возможно на какой срок, была ли оплата)
- суммовые и количественные остатки склада на дату, может быть еще и объемные (в целях планирования складских площадей)
- расчет амортизации, в частности если оборудование возвращается обратно после использования нужно знать на сколько израсходован ресурс
- расчет валовой прибыли по бизнесу (сюда много что входит, в сущности ради этого систему и внедряют)

Вот если заказчику все это будет не нужно, значит у него уже ведется где-то учет и данная система просто добавит геморроя пользователям - двойной ввод данных.

Comment: Да, сейчас ведется в экселях как раз. Я делаю на Ruby On Rails.
Суммы в системе и не должны светиться, будут бумажки с суммами вести.. Я разделил на разные таблицы, чтобы была некоторая история, да и к тому же заказ для завода не сразу выполняется..

Comment: Извините, но это трехколесный велосипед, когда есть бентли за малый рубль.